# удаление окна с текстовым полем и кнопкой удаления

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="message" placeholder="Your username"/>
<button value="Send" onclick="Namer()">Set name</button>
```

мне надо чтобы при нажатие на кнопку  "Set name" удалялась сама кнопка и текстовое поля с Your username я пытался через inner Html но не получается как можно сделать это?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать JavaScript для удаления кнопки и текстового поля. Для этого вам нужно будет добавить обработчик события onclick для кнопки, который будет вызывать функцию для удаления элементов. Пример кода для этого может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="message" placeholder="Your username"/>
<button value="Send" onclick="removeElements()">Set name</button>

<script>
function removeElements() {
  // Получаем элементы с помощью их ID
  var username = document.getElementById('username');
  var button = document.getElementById('button');

  // Удаляем элементы со страницы
  username.parentNode.removeChild(username);
  button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Можно просто использовать метод `remove()`, вместо `parentNode.removeChild(el)`